# Is it fatal if RevertToSelf() after ImpersonateSelf() fails?

Tags: windows, security, winapi, impersonation, privileges

MSDN says that if [RevertToSelf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fails the program should terminate immediately, because otherwise it continues to run in the name of the client being impersonated and that is inappropriate. Now suppose I do

```
ImpersonateSelf( SecurityImpersonation );
```

and the call succeeds, then I call `RevertToSelf()` and the latter fails. The thread continues to run with the privileges of the current process. It it fatally bad too?

Comment: This seems like one of those functions that is impossible to fail.  The only failure scenario I could think of is to deny yourself the "Set Thread Token" permission in the DACL for the thread (or process?) after impersonating yourself (though I am too lazy to try it).  The thing about impersonation is that it affects *everything* the thread tries to access.  I would probably consider failure to be fatal strictly in the sense of being "impossible" and taking precautions (even though there is probably no practical difference between not impersonating and impersonating yourself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like your question, and MSDN is not clear about it.

I looked at [Programming Windows Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604426) (Keith Brown) pages 112 to 117. `ImpersonateSelf` does all the work you could do yourself by calling

- OpenProcessToken
- DuplicateTokenEx(...TokenImpersonation...)
- SetThreadToken
- CloseHandle

While `RevertToSelf` is merely a call to

```
SetThreadToken(0,0)
```

Passing two null parameters instruct the method to revert to the previous token. You don't have to deal with impersonation vs. primary tokens and token access rights. The call will always succeed.

And if you look at `RpcRevertToSelf` function's error codes, you see that RPC related codes aside, the only failure mode is if you are not impersonating.

I say it is safe to assume `RevertToSelf` (called from the same thread as ImpersonateSelf) will always succeed.